# Problem Compiling

Tags: errors, winedt

Forgive me if this off topic, but I am not sure where else to ask. I have a large document of report class. It consists of various chapters, all in separate files. Everything has been going fine, with no problem compiling (using WinEdt), until I added a new subsection to chapter 6. With this new subsection the document will not compile, giving the following error message.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \chapter
            {Lower Bound} \label{ch:6-LowerBound}
? 
! Emergency stop.
l.1 \chapter
            {Lower Bound} \label{ch:6-LowerBound}
End of file on the terminal!
```

When I then undo the change (delete the offending subsection), the document still will not compile. Also, somewhat mysteriously, after the compilation attempt, the list of labels contains only those in Chapter 6 and none of those in the other Chapters. To then get it to compile again I have to delete all the non-TEX files produced during the compile attempt and reboot my machine.

So I then had a go compiling in Texworks and the document compiles (with the subsection that caused the problem in WinEdt). I then make a change to the subsection title (adding $\underline{z}$) and the document will not compile again, this time with the following error message.

```
!Missing $ inserted
<inserted text>
$
l.34 …round \z@ $\relax $}{69}{subsection 6.3.1}
?
```

Unfortunately, I can't provide a MWE as I can't replicate the issue in this manner. Obviously I can't upload the entire project. Do these error messages provide a hint to what is going on?

Comment: Try commenting out the stuff long before these problem lines. Does the problem persist? Also: I doubt rebooting your computer is doing anything useful. And when you're having trouble: it is often good to compile not from within the editor, but from the command line (on Windows, I think it's called the "Command Prompt"..?).

Comment: From the [WinEdt About page](http://www.winedt.com/about.html): "When you set up your project it is important that you set the Main File and build the project tree. The items in the Project Menu (or the associated tool bar buttons) can be used to accomplish the task. If you don't want the Tree/ Navigation Bar visible in your left panel, you should still set the Main File and let WinEdt build the Tree for purposes of automatic referencing. WinEdt builds the project tree based on Input Directives as specified in the Options Interface. [...]" Have you set up the project properly?

Comment: Which document class do you use? Is chapter 6 contained in a separate file?

Comment: @Werner - I believe that I have set it properly.

Comment: @Mico - I am using report class and have each of my chapters in separate files.

Comment: What's in the arguments of the `\subsection` instruction numbered `6.3.1` and of the `\section` instruction numbered `6.3`?

Comment: @Mico 

\section{Evaluating the lower bound I} \label{sec:6-EvaluatingTheLowerBoundI}

\subsection{Step 1 - finding $\underline{z}$} \label{subsec:6-Step1}

If I instead use \subsection{Step 1} \label{subsec:6-Step1} then there is no problem.

Comment: Well, something is going on, and you've given us very little to go on. Note that if you load a package like `sectsty`, it'll make `\underline` fail in things like `\section`.

Comment: What happens if you omit the string `$\underline{z}$`, or if you replace it with `\underline{$z$}`? Do you have any other `\underline` instructions in sectioning-level commands?

Comment: @Mico - I created a bare bones project with just the chapter and sectioning titles and have no problem with the \underline{z} in the section title.

Comment: @Jon - sorry that I can't provide a MWE that replicates the issue (see my comment to Mico above).

Comment: @Mico - I think I have found the problem, purely through trial and error. Removing the line "\tableofcontents" from my main file allows it to compile. Presumably, LaTeX does not like placing $\underline{z}$ in the TOC. Go figure...

Comment: @Freakalien You should really update your question with the important information on what exactly is failing. This way, the question is unclear, and also useless you anybody else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to protect `\underline` in a moving argument such as the section title:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\subsection{Step 1 --- finding $\protect\underline{z}$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If underlining is used for vectors, it makes sense doing `\MakeRobust{\underline}` in the preamble. This requires `\usepackage{fixltx2e}` with a pre-2015 LaTeX kernel.

Comment: @egreg Or, of course, making a robust `\vector` wrapper :) I'll edit this in later in the morning, now I gotta go.

Answer (score 1):

As there seems to be a conflict over the use of `\underline` and/or math-mode material in the Table of Contents, you could try

```
\subsection[Step 1 - finding \b{\textit{z}}]{Step 1 - finding $\underline{z}$}
```

if your document does need a Table of Contents. The material in square brackets -- note that it contains no math-mode material or `\underline` instruction -- will be used for the ToC, and the material in curly braces will be shown in the main part of the document. The lengths of the underlines produced by `\b` and `\underline` aren't quite the same, but I trust no reader will be confused or misled by this difference.

A full MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass{report}
\setcounter{chapter}{6} % just for this example
\setcounter{section}{3} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\subsection[Step 1 - finding \b{\textit{z}}]{Step 1 - finding $\underline{z}$}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem lies with the TOC. Removing the line

```
\tableofcontents
```

allows the project to compile. So, I guess you can't use underlined variables within inline equations in section titles.

Comment: See the other answers for work arounds.